# Check during runtime which persistence provider a Java EE server is using?

Tags: java, class, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I am not looking to find out whether or not a class has been loaded using low-level Reflection API. This question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/482633/1268003) and has some answers. I want to use "clean code", preferably using an API as specified in a Java EE  specification (for example, [JPA 2.1](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338)).

My real problem is that I need to write a patch that applies only for `Hibernate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Java Persistence 2.1](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) specification, section "9.3 Determining the Available Persistence Providers".

### Example

```
PersistenceProviderResolver resolver = PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.getPersistenceProviderResolver();
List<PersistenceProvider> providers = resolver.getPersistenceProviders();
```

Note that there exists a `Persistence.PERSISTENCE_PROVIDER` (*String*) and a `Persistence.providers` (*Set*) but these fields has been deprecated according to their JavaDoc.

The [`PersistenceProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html) interface doesn't say much. But the class behind the interface reveals the provider.

In GlassFish 4.0.1-b08-m1 that bundles **EclipseLink 2.5.2**, only one provider is returned: [`org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider.html).

In WildFly 8.1.0 that bundles **Hibernate 4.3.5**, *two* providers are returned. The second provider's class is [`org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence.html) (*order may be machine dependent?*). According to the class JavaDoc, it has been deprecated in favor of the first provider in the List: [`org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider.html).

Note that the [JPA specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) emphasize that it might not be safe to cache this information:

> In dynamic environments (e.g., OSGi-based environments, containers
>   based on dynamic kernels, etc.), the list of persistence providers may
>   change.

Note also that `PersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders()` is used to " determine the list of available persistence providers". I have not yet understood how to determine *the* persistence provider in use. For example, in WildFly I would like to get hold of just one provider, not two.

### Java 1.8 Solution

```
// "providers" is the variable declared in the example at the beginning
boolean usingHibernate = providers.stream()
        .map(Object::getClass)
        .map(Class::getName)
        .anyMatch(str -> str.startsWith("org.hibernate"));
```

### Java 1.7 Solution

```
boolean usingHibernate = false;

for (PersistenceProvider p : providers) {
    if (p.getClass().getName().startsWith("org.hibernate")) {
        usingHibernate = true;
        break;
    }
}
```