# libgdx - determining which platform is running

Tags: java, android, reflection, libgdx, cross-platform

I have a core project that is converted to 5 different platforms. I need to change some parameters depending the platform that is running. For example if it's android I need to change the ip to the emulator localhost 10.0.0.2 and more.

I tried to determine this using the following answer [In Java, is it possible to know whether a class has already been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482633/in-java-is-it-possible-to-know-whether-a-class-has-already-been-loaded)

but the invoking of any (even non existent) class returned true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Application.getType() method returns the platform the app is currently running on:

```
switch (Gdx.app.getType()) {
    case ApplicationType.Android:
        // android specific code
        break;
    case ApplicationType.Desktop:
        // desktop specific code
        break;
    case ApplicationType.WebGl:
        // HTML5 specific code
        break;
    case ApplicationType.iOS:
        //iOS specific code
        break;
     case ApplicationType.HeadlessDesktop:
        //Headless desktop specific code
        break;
     case ApplicationType.Applet:
        //Applet specific code
        break;
    default:
        // Other platforms specific code
}
```

On Android, one can also query the Android version the application is currently running on:

```
int androidVersion = Gdx.app.getVersion();
```

Here is the [official docs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Application.ApplicationType.html) on the Application#ApplicationType Enum

Comment: iOS simulator returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Application#getType()
```

it will return one of the following outputs: Android, Applet, Desktop, iOS or WebGL.