# How classes of class hierarchy get initialized in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

Debugging sub-expression

`Sub.x`

in expression

`System.out.println(Sub.x);`

in given below code,to understand rule of class initialization in run-time for classes namely., `class Sub` and `class Super` in JVM memory space.

```
package defaultvalues;
import java.util.*;

class Super{
    static int x;
    static{
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super{
    Date date;
    {//instance initialisation block for date
        Calendar temp = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = temp.getTime();
    }
    static{
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }

    long alarm;
}

class Game{
    static Random rand;
    static{
        rand = new Random();
    }
    static void tossCoin(){
        if(rand.nextBoolean()){
            System.out.println("Heads");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Tails");
        }
    }

}
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Sub.x); // class Super is loaded. From class Super, static members are
        //initialised and static initialisation blocks are executed before executing expression 'Sub.x'

        Game.tossCoin(); // class Game is loaded. From class Game, static members are initialised
        //and static initialiser blocks are executed before executing expression 'Game.tossCoin()'
        Sub obj = new Sub(); //instance variables are initialised and instance initialisation block 
        //of class A are executed.
        System.out.println(obj.date);
        System.out.println(obj.alarm);
    }

}
```

After debug, observation is that, `class Super` gets initialized but `class Sub` does not get initialised before expression `Sub.x` gets evaluated. Immediate output after evaluating expression `System.out.println(Sub.x);` is:

```
Super
0
```

So, `System.out.println("Sub");` does not execute before expression `Sub.x` gets evaluated.

With respect to this expression `Sub.x` evaluation, in source code, I see the expression `Sub.x` getting evaluated, `class Super` gets initialized but not `class Sub`.

My question is:

Does `class Sub` get loaded & linked but not initialized before evaluating sub-expression `Sub.x` during run-time?

*Note: Working in Eclipse environment*

Comment: Probably.  If you compile with -Xlint, does the compiler issue a warning that a variable `x` is being accessed through a sub class?

Comment: *"Under the hood, Does javac compiler translate expression Sub.x to Super.x before execution?"* You can check that yourself: run `javap -c Example.class` from the console and see.

Comment: @Tom `javap`  shows this: `3:   getstatic       #22; //Field defaultvalues/Sub.x:I` How do I understand this line?

Comment: So, the compiler doesn't replace something there. It load the static variable `Sub.x` of type `I`nteger.

Comment: @Tom If compiler does not replace expression `Sub.x` with `Super.x`, then, why `class Sub` does not get loaded before sub-expression `Sub.x` gets evaluated?

Comment: Just a heads up, the terms `loaded` and `initialized` are different. I believe you are referring to class initialization in this context (?)

Comment: @vikingsteve yes you are right, am referring to `initialization`

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you describe is given in an example in the JLS, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

> **Example 12.4.1-2. Only The Class That Declares static Field Is
>   Initialized**
>
> ```
> class Super {
>     static int taxi = 1729;
> }
> class Sub extends Super {
>     static { System.out.print("Sub "); }
> }
> class Test {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println(Sub.taxi);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This program prints only:
>
> ```
> 1729
> ```
>
> because the class `Sub` is never initialized; the reference to `Sub.taxi`
>   is a reference to a field actually declared in class `Super` and does
>   not trigger initialization of the class `Sub`.

which matches the list of initialization causes

> - A static field declared by `T` is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

The field is declared by `Super`, not `Sub`.

Comment: For your point: "because the class Sub is never initialized", I understood this point, but how do I verify/confirm if `class Sub` is loaded/linked to JVM instance before sub-expression `Sub.x` gets evaluated?

Comment: @overexchange What specific behavior do you mean by _loaded_? Also, why do you need to confirm it? Seems like a design smell.

Comment: Am talking about these [phases](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html), when I say loaded/linked. As java programmer, I feel, It is important for me to know, whether `class Sub` is loaded in this situation.

Comment: @overexchange You can read the rules of loading in the document you linked to, but, again, what difference will it make whether you know if it happens for your class or not? (Unless you're debugging some classloader issue, but there are better ways to do that.)

Comment: @overexchange You can use techniques described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482633/in-java-is-it-possible-to-know-whether-a-class-has-already-been-loaded) to investigate.

Comment: @overexchange Also, see the [`-verbose:class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) VM argument.

Comment: One supplementary, As per your [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482633/in-java-is-it-possible-to-know-whether-a-class-has-already-been-loaded), Is `class ClassLoader` known as bootstrap class loader?

Comment: The boostrap class loader is a `ClassLoader` subclass provided by the JRE that starts everything.

Comment: what is the name of that subclass(bootstrap class loader)?

Comment: @overexchange It depends on the JRE. It's an implementation detail. I believe you can get a reference to it with `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you haven't triggered `static class initialization` yet.

In the answer to a related question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization), the answer talks about the various ways to trigger class initialization.

If you made a method `getX()` in class `Sub` which returns `x` from it's superclass, it should perform static class initialization for `Sub`.

Some more reading in [JLS-12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

Note in this case that "A static field declared by T is assigned." does not seem to apply, since `x` was declared in the superclass.

Comment: Can I say, `class Sub` gets loaded & linked but not initialized before expression `Sub.x` is evaluated?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is true.

Comment: Can I confirm this by writing java code(to verify load/link) in the above program?

Comment: The line `Sub obj = new Sub();` already triggers static class initialization of class `Sub`, but if you want to trigger it earlier, you can for example just add this to Sub class: `static int n;` and then access it somehow, e.g. `System.out.println(Sub.n);`.