# In Java, is it possible to know whether a class has already been loaded when using the bootstrap loader?

Tags: java, classloader

This is a variation of [In Java, is it possible to know whether a class has already been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482633/in-java-is-it-possible-to-know-whether-a-class-has-already-been-loaded). Our app does byte code instrumentation and makes use of the -Xbootclasspath/a: option to be able to instrument the Java runtime.  I would like to know if a class has been loaded via the bootstrap loader - without attempting to load it.

The code listed in the referenced query will not work if class was loaded by bootstrap loader - as I don't believe there is any way to get an instance of the bootstrap loader to use in the invoke.

Any thoughts?  I suspect it can't be done.  It's not critical to our application but I am curious.

Comment: I'm curious about this too. Is the system class loader not available yet when your code executes?

Comment: Does “our app does byte code instrumentation” imply that you are implementing a Java Agent?

Comment: Yes, we have a Java Agent that implements a ClassFileTransformer.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to perform runtime byte code instrumentation, you should implement a Java Agent using [the Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html#package.description).

The Java Agent will get an [`Instrumentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) instance in its `premain` or `agentmain` method when its parameter types have been declared as `(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst)`.

This API allows [appending jar files to the bootstrap class path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch-java.util.jar.JarFile-) at runtime, so you don’t need to rely on the `-Xbootclasspath/a` option being specified on the command line.

Further, it has the methods [`getAllLoadedClasses()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses--) and [`getInitiatedClasses(ClassLoader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getInitiatedClasses-java.lang.ClassLoader-) to query already loaded classes. So you can use `getInitiatedClasses(null)` to get all classes currently loaded by the bootstrap loader. You have to iterate them and compare the names yourself to find out whether a particular class in contained is the array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, crazy idea.

You can use the same technique in the thread you described, trying a different method. Class ClassLoader has the following method:

```
private Class<?> findBootstrapClassOrNull(String name)
```

This method calls a native method:

```
private native Class<?> findBootstrapClass(String name)
```

Which you could try to make accessible too.

EDIT: I've tried the following code, running from application class loader, though:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws NoSuchMethodException,
            InvocationTargetException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        Method method = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                "findBootstrapClass", String.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        MyClassLoader cl = new MyClassLoader();
        System.out.println(method.invoke(cl, "java.lang.String"));
        System.out.println(method.invoke(cl, "sun.java2d.loops.GraphicsPrimitiveMgr$2"));
    }
}
```

(By the way, this code does not have to extend ClassLoader, I just left that from a previous test where I was invoking a protected method from ClassLoader.)

Whatever classes I provide, at the point my main method is running, it appears pretty much everything is loaded, not sure. From the source code for the "findBootstrapClass" method, I see this:

```
    /**
     * Returns a class loaded by the bootstrap class loader;
     * or return null if not found.
     */
    private Class<?> findBootstrapClassOrNull(String name)
```

So, unless you get different result running at the time the code is being instrumented, I'm thinking perhaps this is not doable.

NOTE: again, the source code that I looked at is for OpenJDK 1.8

Good luck.

Comment: The reason why every class appears to be loaded when calling this method, is that this method *will load* the class. As its documentation comment says, it will only return `null` if the class has not been found.